# Background Color for nav-items on responsive adjustment of navbar in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hey I've created a navbar from bootstrap 4 but whenever I try to test the responsiveness of my page it loses the background color of my nav-items. All it shows is the text. Can someone help me keep the navbar color whenever I click the toggler link. Below is my code for html and css.

I would like the navbar to look like what a dropdown menu would like. With matching background color of the navbar.

```css
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;   
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #555;
    }
    p{
        color: #555;
    }
    .header{
        background: radial-gradient(#fff,#ffd6d6);
    }
    
    .container{
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin: auto;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        
    }
    .navbar{
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        min-height:22px;
        
    }
    .navbar.navbar-inverse {
        border: none;
      }
    .navbar .navbar-brand img {
        height: 85px;
        padding-left: 39%;
      }
      .navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a.nav-link {
        color: #fff;
      }
      #navbarMenu{
        align-items: flex-end;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-danger navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom ">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                             Only Store
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarMenu">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home<span class="sr-only"></span> </a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Account</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                        <img src="Images/cart.png" width="30px" height="30px">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="menutoggle"></a>
                                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        
                    </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the background colour to the .collapse and child ul within it?

Please see what I mean below:

```css
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;   
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #555;
    }
    p{
        color: #555;
    }
    .header{
        background: radial-gradient(#fff,#ffd6d6);
    }
    .collapse, ul {
        background-color: #121212; 
    }
    .container{
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin: auto;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        
    }
    .navbar{
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        min-height:22px;
        
    }
    .navbar.navbar-inverse {
        border: none;
      }
    .navbar .navbar-brand img {
        height: 85px;
        padding-left: 39%;
      }
      .navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a.nav-link {
        color: #fff;
      }
      #navbarMenu{
        align-items: flex-end;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-danger navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom ">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                             Only Store
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarMenu">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home<span class="sr-only"></span> </a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Products</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Account</a> 
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                        <img src="Images/cart.png" width="30px" height="30px">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="menutoggle"></a>
                                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        
                    </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes! It ended up working. I still need to add a hover feature for a highlighted look. How would I cast a color over the navbar(background-color) to match the color of the dropdown view  in the CSS.